# Spring Integration Sample :: Aggregator

Tags: spring-integration

I am looking into the aggregator sample in spring-projects/spring-integration-samples.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/applications/cafe/cafe-si/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/cafeDemo-xml.xml

```
<int:aggregator input-channel="preparedDrinks"  method="prepareDelivery" output-channel="deliveries">
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.samples.cafe.xml.Waiter"/>
</int:aggregator>


public class Waiter {

    public Delivery prepareDelivery(List<Drink> drinks) {
        return new Delivery(drinks);
    }

}
```

The Waiter class does not specify any correlation /release strategy.  How are the items are aggregated/group released?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you don't specify `correlation-strategy` and `release-strategy`, the default are used - `HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy` for the `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID` header and `SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy` based on the `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_NUMBER` and `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_SIZE`.

That is exactly what `<splitter>` produces with its default `applySequence`.

All the info is exactly in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator).